# Handle AJAX callback either render partial or redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have an AJAX call to load a modal but I have a `before_action` if `consent settings` are switched off `redirect_to` settings page.

**AJAX call**

```
$(document).on 'click', '#add-consent-form-template, #edit-consent-form-template', (e) ->
  $.ajax(url: $(this).attr('data-url')).done (html) ->
    $("#modal-consent-form-content").html html
    $("#modal-consent-form").modal('show')
    $('.date_picker').each ->
      $(this).datepicker
        showOn: 'both'
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        altField: $(this).next()
        minDate : 0
    $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').addClass('fa fa-calendar fa-lg mar-left-10')
    $('.description .widget').height($('.study-graph .widget').height())
  e.preventDefault()
```

**Normal case** (If consent settings are ON)

```
render partial: 'add_consent_form_template_modal', layout: false
```

**Error Case** (If consent settings are OFF)

```
set_flash(error: 'Consent Forms are disabled. Please turn on Consent Forms first.')
redirect_to edit_study_path(id: @study)
```

**Problem**

In `redirect_to` case, it renders the whole settings page in the modal. How can I handle the AJAX callback to render the partial or redirect to settings page?

Comment: You can't redirect from ajax call.

Comment: Is there anyway to abort AJAX callback? That If it `redirect_to` but not come to AJAX callback?

Comment: Dont use `redirect_to`. Just return the `path` to redirect and use `window.location = path` on client.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am actually trying but how I determine if I am getting `html` or `path`?

Comment: by status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case when your control is going on AJAX callback and you want to `redirect_to` to `settings` and not want to render it on modal, just pass `nil` as HTML.

```
set_flash(error: 'Consent Forms are disabled. Please turn on Consent Forms first.')
render html: nil
```

And in you Javascript/CoffeeScript you can simply check `length` on you `html`.

```
$(document).on 'click', '#add-consent-form-template, #edit-consent-form-template', (e) ->
  $.ajax(url: $(this).attr('data-url')).done (html) ->
    if html.length > 0
      $("#modal-consent-form-content").html html
      $("#modal-consent-form").modal('show')
      $('.date_picker').each ->
        $(this).datepicker
          showOn: 'both'
          dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
          altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
          altField: $(this).next()
          minDate : 0
      $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').addClass('fa fa-calendar fa-lg mar-left-10')
      $('.description .widget').height($('.study-graph .widget').height())
    else
      window.location.href = <Link to your settings page>
  e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

in youre action

write below code, please add if condition as per your requirement

```
if consent == ON
   render partial: 'add_consent_form_template_modal', layout: false
else
   set_flash(error: 'Consent Forms are disabled. Please turn on Consent Forms first.')
redirect_to edit_study_path(id: @study) and return
end
```